# Removing an item in Dictionary using the Value of the item [ not by key ]

Tags: c#, generics, dictionary, collections

I am having an **Dictionary[int,Ibooks]**, where ***Ibooks*** is an interface having ***bookname*** and ***author*** as properties.

I have tired to remove the dictionary ***item by value*** using the **keyvaluepair**.

this is my code :

```
 public override void remove()
 {
     Dictionary<int, Ibooks > books = new Dictionary<int, Ibooks>();
     Console.WriteLine("Enter the value to be removed : ");

     string value = Console.ReadLine(); 

     //var item=books.First<kvp.Value == value >;

     foreach (var item in books.Where(kvp => kvp.Value == value).ToDictionary()) //error line
     {
         books.Remove(item);
     }
}
```

**Ibook Interface:**

```
interface Ibooks
    {
        string bookname { get; set; }
        string author { get; set; }
    }
```

but i got this error :

**"operator == cant be applied to types of Dictionary.Ibooks and string"**

Can anyone have an idea to solve this or else is there any other better way to find an element by its value ? ?

For example ,

My input is bookname= "dbms" it should remove the particualr book from the dictionary.

But i was unable compare with the particular value "bookname". Since the interface has both author and bookname as properties.

Comment: how can u compare a string and an Interface instead you just read the value of the variable that you want compare from the Interface and check equality

Comment: `books.Where(kvp => kvp.Value == value)` looks wierd. Probably you meant something like this `books.Where(kvp => kvp.Value.bookname == value)`

Comment: the values in the interface is string so i tried like that..However i try to typecast it to interface it doesnt work

Comment: @Sripremrookie can you please show us the interface and the value that you want to compare so that we can help you

Comment: i had edited my question.see the interface and the value i had try to compare

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This statement is not correct:

> var item in books.Where(kvp => kvp.Value == value)

you are comparing `IBooks` with `string` that's causing build error.

Note that the value is of type `string`:

> > string value = Console.ReadLine()

Compare with string property `BookName` of `IBook`.

you have to do something like this:

> > > var item in books.Where(kvp => kvp.Value.BookName  == value)

Comment: so what else i have to do to compare with that particular property in interface

Comment: compare with specific property **bookname**

Answer (score 1):

Everyone else has already explained a bunch of different ways to do this, but I'd like to go on the record here to say that I think you're fundamentally misusing the Dictionary object. Most of the concept of a dictionary is adding and referencing values by key. You're doing this exactly backwards, and there's a reason everyone's solution is 80-character LINQ queries. If you want to store references to books with an int (presumably an ISBN?) as a key, use the key to delete them. If you want the user to be able to delete books based on their title, use the title as a key. What you have now is overly complicated, and finding ways to double down on that complexity as a temporary solution isn't going to help you at all.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `kvp.Value` refers to an `Ibooks` instance. If you're trying to match a bookname that the user entered, change that to `kvp.Value.bookname`. If you're trying to match an author, then change it to `kvp.Value.author`.

Answer (score 0):

You actually shoud use somthing like this

```
foreach (var item in books.Where(kvp => kvp.Value.bookname == value).ToDictionary())
```

It's happen becouse you try to compare an interface and string (and compiler told you about it).

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
foreach (var item in books.Where(kvp => kvp.Value.bookname.equlas(value)).ToDictionary())
    books.Remove(item.Key);
```

Answer (score 0):

At last this solved my problem,

```
        Console.WriteLine("Enter te bookname");
        string searchvalue=Console.ReadLine ();

        foreach (var item in books.Where(kvp => kvp.Value.bookname == searchvalue ))
        {

            books.Remove(item.Key);

        }
```